# setattr and assignment are not equivalent for private attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, cpython, setattr

Using CPython 3.4.3 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)), i encounter a very weird behavior when using `setattr` and `getattr` on private attribute:

```
class Short:
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, '__myatt', None)
        self.__myatt = 42
        assert getattr(self, '__myatt') is None
Short()
```

This last code never raise any `AssertionError`, despite the affectation before the assertion statement.
However, the same code with `myattr` instead of `__myatt` properly raise the exception:

```
class Short:
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, 'myatt', None)
        self.myatt = 42
        assert getattr(self, 'myatt') is 42
Short()
```

---

Here is a comparison of the two cases (private vs public), with annotations and assertions, showing that 2 of the 3 means of access don't returns the expected value:

```
class Private:

    def __init__(self):
        print('############### PRIVATE ###############')
        print('Assign __fa with None using setattr.')
        setattr(self, '__fa', None)


        print("Set __fa to 42 using regular affectation.")
        new_value = 42
        self.__fa = new_value

        print("\nPrint the new values. Expected to be all 42:")
        print("new value:", new_value)
        print("self.__fa:", self.__fa)
        print("getattr(self, '__fa'):", getattr(self, '__fa'))
        print("self.__dict__['__fa']:", self.__dict__['__fa'])

        assert self.__dict__['__fa'] is None  # this is unexpected
        assert getattr(self, '__fa') is None  # this is unexpected

        print("\nNow modify __fa using setattr")
        # Maintenant, on utilise la notation «équivalente» (d'après la doc)
        setattr(self, '__fa', new_value)

        print("\nPrint the new values. Expected to be all 42:")
        # et tout va bien !
        # WTF !
        print("new value:", new_value)
        print("self.__fa:", self.__fa)
        print("getattr(self, '__fa'):", getattr(self, '__fa'))
        print("self.__dict__['__fa']:", self.__dict__['__fa'])

        assert self.__fa is not None


class Public:

    def __init__(self):
        print('\n############### PUBLIC ###############')
        print('Assign fa with None using setattr.')
        setattr(self, 'fa', None)


        print("Set fa to 42 using regular affectation.")
        new_value = 42
        self.fa = new_value

        print("\nPrint the new values. Expected to be all 42:")
        print("new value:", new_value)
        print("self.fa:", self.fa)
        print("getattr(self, 'fa'):", getattr(self, 'fa'))
        print("self.__dict__['fa']:", self.__dict__['fa'])

        assert self.__dict__['fa'] is not None  # this is expected
        assert getattr(self, 'fa') is not None  # this is expected


Private()
Public()
```

Is this behavior expected ? Why and what is its origin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. Name mangling, performed at compilation time, leaves string literals untouched, as such you should explicitly provide the mangled names in `getattr`,`setattr` and `hasattr`:

```
class Short:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__myatt = 42
        # print(getattr(self, '__myatt'))  # Fails with a NameError 
        print(getattr(self, '_{0.__qualname__}__myatt'.format(type(self))))  # Succeeds
```

Which now prints out `42`. Similarly, for `setattr` to set, `hasattr` to check, you'd need to provide the mangled name.

This was brought up in a relevant [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue8264) for `hasattr` were yes, it is explicitly stated as expected behavior.